# importing unnecessary libraries when `virtualenv .`

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup plain python3 virtual environment.

I created my virtual environment and activate it

```
virtualenv . && source bin/activate
```

But when I `python3 --version` and `pip3 freeze`, I see more than default python3 libraries.

**Here is `python3 --version` output**

```
(socketdirectory) lawn-143-215-57-83:socketdirectory jaeminbaek$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
```

**This is `pip3 freeze` result output**

```
zewn-143-215-57-83:socketdirectory mycomputer$ source bin/activate pip3 freeze
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
bleach==1.5.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
configparser==3.5.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.11.4
django-allauth==0.32.0
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-filter==1.0.4
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
djangorestframework==3.6.3
enum34==1.1.6
flake8==3.4.1
flake8-docstrings==1.1.0
flake8-polyfill==1.0.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.5
Keras==2.0.6
Markdown==2.6.8
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.13.1
oauthlib==2.0.2
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.2.1
protobuf==3.3.0
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pydocstyle==2.0.0
pyflakes==1.5.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.3
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
tensorflow==1.2.1
Theano==0.9.0
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

Why is it importing so many libraries?

**UPDATE** I'm getting this error when I use `virtualenv -p python3 venv`

```
lawn-143-215-57-83:socketdirectory jaeminbaek$ virtualenv -p python3 venv 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/jaeminbaek/anaconda/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Users/jaeminbaek/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socketdirectory/venv/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socketdirectory/venv/bin/python (you must use /Users/jaeminba
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socketdirectory/venv/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socketdirectory/venv/bin/python3 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socketdirectory' (should be '/Users/jaeminbaek/Desktop/cs3251/socket
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
lawn-143-215-57-83:socketdirectory jaeminbaek$
```

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/305) suggest that you shouldn’t be using virtualenv with Anaconda.

Comment: I didnt call anaconda.???

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The output `Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)` suggests that you used conda to install Python 3, in which case you shouldn't be using virtualenv.

Comment: What should I do then? to create virtualenv? SHould I delete ananconda package -> reinstall python3 and make virtualenv?

Comment: The link that I posted before has instructions for creating a conda environment. Or if you want to use virtualenv you could install Python 3 a different way.

Comment: Can I keep the conda and install py3?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Since I can call `python3`, python3 is already installed on my computer. What you're trying to say is the python3 package is instlaled by Anaconda, so I can't use that python3 package for virtualenv. My question is ... if I already have python3 on my computer, how am I supposed to download python3 again??? Should I delete the anaconda?

Comment: These questions have gone off topic from your original question. I can't guide you through installing Python. I haven't used conda before so can't offer any tips about that. However I don't think you necessarily need to delete it. As for *how am I supposed to download python3 again*, as a first step you could try searching "download python".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating virtual environment with python 2.7

```
pip freeze
```

When you fire which pip3 it will not show you the pip under new virtual env, it will show the global pip3, that contains many libraries.

For pip3 to execute you should create virtual environment by giving python3 flag explicitly

```
virtualenv -p python3 . && source bin/activate
pip3 freeze
pip freeze
```

This will give you the correct result. To crosscheck always fire command

```
which pip
which pip3
```

Above command will show you which pip is you are using. In your case, usr/bin/pip3 was used

Comment: `virtualenv -p python3 .(or venv)` doesn't work in this case. Can you check my edited question?